# The 2nd verse of Baqarah say: "this is the book", But wasn't the Quran sent down as a "revelation"?

Tags: tafseer, surat-al-baqarah

Al-Baqarah [2:2](http://quran.com/2/2) states:

> This is the Book; in it is guidance sure, without doubt, to those who fear Allah;

Keeping in view of the above Ayat, wasn't the Quran sent down as a "revelation" to Prophet Muhammad?  Furthermore,  it wasn't compiled as a book till several years till after his death.

My question is, why is this Ayat referring to Quran as a book?

Comment: Very very interressting question, maybe because Allah knew..?

Comment: Or maybe words were changed during compilation?

Comment: That is impossible. Nothing is changed. There is even a surah where it states that the holy Quran is protected against changes.

Comment: Allah has taken responsibility to protect Qur'an.

Answer (score 4):

> My question is, why is this Ayat referring to Quran as a book?

This needs to be understood along with other ayats.

In Surah aali Imran 3:81 =

> And when Allah took the covenant
>   of the prophets, [saying], "Whatever I give you of al-Kitab and
>   wisdom and then there comes to you a messenger confirming what is with
>   you, you [must] believe in him and support him." [Allah] said, "Have
>   you acknowledged and taken upon that My commitment?" They said, "We
>   have acknowledged it." He said, "Then bear witness, and I am with you
>   among the witnesses."

In surah Younus 10:37 =

> And it was not for this Quran to be produced by other than
>   Allah, but [it is] a confirmation of what was before it and a
>   detailed explanation of al-Kitab, about which there is
>   no doubt, from the Lord of the worlds.

And in surah ar-Ra'd 13:39 =

> Allah eliminates what He wills or confirms, and with Him is the Mother
>   of the Book.

So *al-Kitab* is the mother of the book with Allah, and from it is what all the revelation was revealed to the prophets, and the Quran is what explains the revelation.

Comment: **mother of book** is little different to me. When I read it in our language, we read **Al-Lauh Al-Mahfuz**. What does Mother of Book means.

Comment: @Murtaza, Um ul-Kitab and Al-luk al-Mahfuz both find mention in the Quran to refer to a primordial Divine treasure that includes all truth. Scriptural revelations are considered to emanate from that.

Answer (score 2):

In English a [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book) means the literal meaning that we all know:

> A book is a set of written, printed, illustrated, or blank sheets, made of ink, paper, parchment, or other materials, usually fastened together to hinge at one side.

However, in Arabic a book can mean [many other things](http://www.almaany.com/home.php?language=arabic&lang_name=english&word=%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8):

> - manual ; record ; register ; textbook
> - a copy of the (Holy) koran
> - letter ; message ; note
> - book ; compilation ; publication ; volume ; work ; writing
> - elementary school ; school
> - a primary school
> - institution for educating pupils
> - a shool for educating the little children

In the context of these verses koran means a guide:

> in it is guidance sure

Comment: Well the first 4 synonyms refer to كِتَاب which means book (and is the TOPIC of this Question, as that's the word quoted in that Verse), and the others refer to كُتَّاب which is a kind of school/Qur'an school! So only the 1st 4 synonyms apply here! And you forgot the other synonyms for كِتَاب  on the site: 
manual ; record ; register ; textbook etc.

Answer (score 2):

Allah says:

ذَٰلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ ۛ فِيهِ هُدًى لِّلْمُتَّقِينَ

THAT is the Book, no doubt in it, a guidance for those who have taqwa. (Quran 2:2)

"That", as opposed to "this", implies something distant.

Answer (score 1):

Allah says:

**ذَٰلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ ۛ فِيهِ هُدًى لِّلْمُتَّقِينَ**

**THAT is the Book, no doubt in it, a guidance for those who have taqwa.** (Quran 2:2)

"That", as opposed to "this", implies something distant.

**إِنَّا جَعَلْنَاهُ قُرْآنًا عَرَبِيًّا لَّعَلَّكُمْ تَعْقِلُونَ**

**Indeed, We have made it an Arabic recitation so that you understand.** (Quran 43:3)

**وَإِنَّهُ فِي أُمِّ الْكِتَابِ لَدَيْنَا لَعَلِيٌّ حَكِيمٌ**

**And indeed it is in the Mother of the Book with Us, Exalted, Wise.** (Quran 43:4)

Answer (score 0):

Al-Qur’an literally means ‘The Recitation’, and is an excerpt from the Book of Knowledge, Book of Records, Book of Nature or Master Plan – an allegorical representation. The Quran is a compilation, an explanation, and a reading within, and of, this Book
85:21 in fact, this is an exalted, sublime compilation and recitation (Quran)
85:22 within the preserved, imperishable tablet

This needs to be understood along with other verses as well.
10:37 And it was not for this Quran to be produced by other than Allah, but [it is] a confirmation of what was before it and a detailed explanation of the Book, about which there is no doubt, from the Lord of the worlds.
The Book (of Nature), about which there is no doubt, is explained via prior revelations, and culminates within the Quran.

12:1 These are the signs of the clear Book
12: Indeed, We have sent it down as an Arabic (clear, plain, distinct) Quran (compilation, reading) so that you may understand
13:39 Allah eliminates what He wills or confirms, and with Him is the Mother of the Book.
So umm-ul-Kitab is the mother of the book (Book of Records, Book of Nature or Master Plan) with Allah. From it is comes the revelation to the prophets; thus, the Quran is the collection, compilation, explanation and recitation of it.