# Can the Qur'an be referred to as The Good Book?

Tags: quran

The [Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible) is sometimes informally referred to as "The Good Book".  I'm wondering if it's appropriate to refer to the Qur'an as "The Good Book" (assuming [it is a book](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38922/17163), which I think is only debatable on a philosophical level).

**Question**: Can the Qur'an be referred to as The Good Book?

Googling [`qur'an "the good book"`](https://www.google.com/#q=qur%27an+%22the+good+book) didn't give any relevant hits on the front page, which suggests the Qur'an is not commonly referred to as The Good Book.

It may simply be too impractical to do so, as people may misinterpret someone saying The Good Book to refer to the Qur'an as instead meaning the Bible.

Comment: I am not aware of that exact wordings but 
78:2 might be something. Tafsir Tabari mentions: "واختلف أهل التأويل في المعنيّ بالنبأ العظيم، فقال بعضهم: أريد به القرآن."

Comment: There is no Islamic precedent for such a title, and copying a title of the bible just for the sake of it would likely be *haram* as it would come under [imitating](https://islamqa.info/en/45200) other religions. The Quran does have [titles of its own](http://www.iqra.net/names/QuranNames.html), and it would be more suitable to address it with them.

Comment: @Rebecca J. Stones, I reckon yeah, why not. Actually the reality is so, but unfortunately the Orf (custom) ... Anyway, you asked a great fact/question. جزاکم الله خیرا.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the Qur'an be referred to as The Good Book?

**Yes, of course.**
But, unfortunately, as you yourself pointed out, "The Bible is sometimes informally referred to as "The Good Book"". But the reality is that the real "The Good Book" is the Holy Qur'an which conveys everyone to success.

Of course, the intelligent and fair people are aware that just the name doesn't prove its superiority. For instance, there are books with nice names such as: Sahih-of-x/y, etc. but choosing/being famous of Sahih for those books doesn't prove their correctness and so on.

About the issue of the Holy Qur'an, it seems a difficult act to promote such truth/phrase as you correctly remarked the Qur'an as "The Good Book", but it needs a very vast helping and support of other Muslims to promote that.

**Conclusion:**

The answer of your fantastic question (as a reality) is that yes it can, but unfortunately as a custom some/many people apparently (as you mentioned) refer to some other book.

Answer (score 0):

Allah is good, Allah has attribute of speech, the Quran is speech of Allah. Therefore the Quran is good.

> O people, **Allah is Good** and He therefore, accepts only that which is good.
>   https://sunnah.com/muslim/12/83

Angels say Allah spoke truth.

> What is it that your Lord has said?" They will say: "The Truth; and He is the Most High, the Most Great."" (Qur'an 34:23)

Isn't True speech good?